# Método en JS concatena precios y no los suma

Tags: javascript

Buenas quería saber como puedo calcular el precio total de mis productos, el fallo esta en la ultima funcion pero no se como hacer que los calcule todos, me los pone uno al lado de otro , osea los concatena en forma de string, pero con el parse tampoco me deja
Dejo mi código

```
       const vm = new Vue({
        el: 'main',
        data: {
            nuevo_Videojuego: "",
            nuevo_Precio: "",
            totalDinero: "",
            juegos: [
                {titulo: "Spider-Man", precio: "49.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                {titulo: "FIFA 2019", precio: "79.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                {titulo: "Fortnite", precio: "0.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                {titulo: "Red Dead Redemption 2", precio: "59.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                {titulo: "Call of Duty: Black Ops 4", precio: "69.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                {titulo: "Destiny 22", precio: "39.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
            ]
        },
computed:{
            totalPrecio: function () {
                var total=0;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.juegos.length; i++) {
                    total+=this.juegos[i].precio;
                }
                return total;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo modificaría de este modo:

- No veo eficiente que hagas uso de un ciclo `for` que hace verboso tu código para una estructura como la que presentas; revisa el uso de `for of`
- En el ciclo accedo a la clave de precio de esta forma: `clave.precio`; en este caso sería **`elemento.precio`**
- Tomo la clave que ya declaraste en tu instancia de Vue llamada `totalDinero` indicando su *scope* por medio de `this` para que esta asuma el papel de acumulador de la sumatoria de precios que se irá haciendo por cada iteración que haga el ciclo
- Dentro del ciclo hago la suma, para que acumule dichos valores
- Por fuera del ciclo y dentro del método hago el `return` de la cantidad total en la variable `totalDinero`
- Para evitar que los valores se concatenen, paso como parámetro al valor numérico recuperado para que lo interprete como un valor numérico en la función `Number` ya que como tu mismo observas el valor de precio almacenado es de tipo **string**
- Por cierto tu propiedad o clave `totalDinero` no la iguales con unas comillas vacías puesto que lo que guardará es la sumatoria de una cantidad numérica; mejor inicializa dicha clave con 0
- Descarta el uso de esa variable `total` ya que al menos hasta ahorita no veo motivo de su existencia

**Código**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo de sumatoria en VueJS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
      {{ totalPrecio }}
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
       const vm = new Vue({
            el: '#main',
            data: {
                nuevo_Videojuego: "",
                nuevo_Precio: "",
                totalDinero: 0,
                juegos: [
                    {titulo: "Spider-Man", precio: "49.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                    {titulo: "FIFA 2019", precio: "79.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                    {titulo: "Fortnite", precio: "0.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                    {titulo: "Red Dead Redemption 2", precio: "59.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                    {titulo: "Call of Duty: Black Ops 4", precio: "69.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                    {titulo: "Destiny 22", precio: "39.99", existencias: 5, total: 0},
                ]
            },
             computed: {
                totalPrecio() {
                  for(elemento of this.juegos) {
                    this.totalDinero += Number(elemento.precio)
                  }
                  return this.totalDinero
                }
             }
       })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma

```
totalPrecio: function () {
  var total=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.juegos.length; i++) {
    total = total + this.juegos[i].precio;
  }
  return total;
}
```

Ya que si haces `total += precio` solo harás que los números se concatenen y no se sumara ninguno.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya indica Aprendiz en su detallada respuesta, el problema principal es que precio está definido como `string`, por eso el operador `+` realiza la concatenación en vez de la suma.

A mi entender, la suya es la respuesta correcta, yo me limito a ofrecer una alternativa, usando `map` para devolver un array de precios como números y `reduce` para hacer la suma sin usar acumuladores, pero que es una cuestión de preferencia personal en la forma de escribir código.

Yo lo haría así:

```
computed: {
                totalPrecio() {
                  return this.juegos.map((j) => Number(j.precio)).reduce((p1,p2) => p1 + p2, 0);
                }
             }
```

Comment: Además de publicar el código deberías explicar por qué consideras que el código soluciona el problema.